# Playing and plotting audio in Matlab

Tags: matlab, audio, interface

I'm new to Matlab and I want to implement an audio interface in Matlab. What it should do is to be able to play a wav file, show me a plot of the audio and have a pointer (or line) that traverse the plot in sync with the audio.

How can I synchronise such a pointer with audio signal? Thanks a lot.

Comment: For the first part: check out `sound`, `soundsc`. For the second: good old `plot`. For the third: `sound` and `soundsc` will be of no help, as they are asynchronous. Maybe `audioplayer/playblocking`?

Comment: You can use `wavread` to get the audio samples and the sampling rate. `audioplayer` can be used to play the audio. You can use `get(CurrentSample)` on the audioplayer object. As @LuisMendo has pointed out `plot` is effective to to plot time-domain data. `line` can be used to draw a vertical line in a plot, which has to be erased and redrawn in a loop as each sample is played.

Comment: Checkout code for a simpe audio editor in file exchange at http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/19873-simple-audio-editor. It can play audio and show a pointer. I am the author.